# Hierarchical tables with vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I need to display some tree structures on an application I'm working on. The sample data would be something like this:

```
Category 1
       - Subcategory 1.1
                - Subcategory 1.1.1:     5 items
                - Subcategory 1.1.2:     6 items
       - Subcategory 1.2
                - Subcategory 1.2.1:     2 items
Category 2
       - Subcategory 2.1
                - Subcategory 2.2.1:     5 items
                - Subcategory 2.2.2:     6 items
                - Subcategory 2.2.3:     5 items
                - Subcategory 2.2.4:     6 items
```

So I need to put this on a table for which i need to alter the rowspan on the parent groups. The thing is that I have no idea how to do that with Vuejs. I tried with v-for structures on the three levels, but I'm seriously lost. Has anyone done something similar with Vue?

Comment: It's not clear how you would draw such a table. Can you make a sample table in ASCII? Using something like Monodraw or ASCIIflow?

Comment: You can check out this example: http://vuejs.org/examples/tree-view.html

Comment: On a table, even with nested data, I encountered problems with opening and closing of the tags and the v-for. So it might not be possible to do this with a table. Other structures might be possible (where each level uses a different tag, div, span, etc).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using CSS Grid to build the table.  You could conditionally assign CSS rules ( :class ) to progressively indent.  For example .level__2 { margin-left: 24px;}